# Unable to connect to GridDB server with PHP client

Tags: griddb

I installed Griddb server with name "griddbba" in an ubuntu virtual machine and I installed GridDB PHP client in another machine.

I run sample1.php found [here](https://github.com/griddb/php_client)  using CLI as below:

```
php sample/sample1.php 239.0.0.1 31999 griddbba admin admin
```

Then I get an error message as below:

```
[0]
10053

[10053:TXN_CLUSTER_NAME_INVALID] Failover timed out (trialCount=71, reconnectedTrial=-1, failureMillis=120711, reason=cluster name invalid (input=griddbba, current=griddbubuntu))

[1]
10053

[10053:TXN_CLUSTER_NAME_INVALID] cluster name invalid (input=griddbba, current=griddbubuntu)

[2]
10053

[10053:TXN_CLUSTER_NAME_INVALID] cluster name invalid (input=griddbba, current=griddbubuntu)
```

As you can see, I am unable to connect to the Griddb server from another machine.

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your clusterName might be something different. Make sure to check your "clusterName" it looks like your cluster name might be something different. Type the following command:

```
$cat /var/lib/gridstore/conf/gs_cluster.json | grep clusterName
$"clusterName":"sample",
```

and you can see clusterName is called "sample". I am using CentOS 7.x so depending on your OS it might be in a different directory (just find the gs_cluster.json file for the information.